# How to calculate the maximum occurence in a rolling window?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, rolling-computation

Say I have a table as follows:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Type       | Incident ID     | Date of incident|
--------------------------------------------------
| A          | 1               | 2022-02-12      |
| A          | 2               | 2022-02-14      |
| A          | 3               | 2022-02-14      |
| A          | 4               | 2022-02-14      |
| A          | 5               | 2022-02-16      |
| A          | 6               | 2022-02-17      |
| A          | 7               | 2022-02-19      |
| A          | 8               | 2022-02-19      |
| A          | 7               | 2022-02-19      |
| A          | 8               | 2022-02-19      |

 ...          ...               ...             

| B          | 1               | 2022-02-12      |
| B          | 2               | 2022-02-12      |
| B          | 3               | 2022-02-13      |

 ...          ...               ...             

--------------------------------------------------
```

This is a list of different types of incidents. Every incident has a type, an id and a date, at which it occurred. This is just an example to help understand my goal.

What I want is - for a given range, e.g. 5 days - the maximum value that a rolling sum over these incidents would become:

So I would start with all elements that fall into the first 5 days and accumulate the occurences: 6.

```
2022-02-12 - 2022-02-17:    6
```

By starting to roll the window by one day, all elements of the first day get eliminated from the sum, in this case -1 and no element for the next day in line gets added. The next value would be 5.

```
2022-02-13 - 2022-02-18:    5
```

6 > 5. So 6 is still the maximum occurence of incidents in a 5 day window.

Continue for the complete time range.

This is not that hard to achieve but how would I do this in a very efficient manner for millions of elements? In short: I want to create a moving window of a fixed date range (e.g. 5 days), count all occurances for this window and give out the maximum value that was reached for any window.

By the way I am using sqlalchemy, but I would also be interested in plain sql.

An appropriate test set would be this:

```
test_data_small = {'Id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
                                6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
                                0, 1, 2, 3],
                   'Type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
                               'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
                               'A', 'A', 'B', 'B',
                               'B', 'B'],
                   'Date': [
                       '2022-02-12', '2022-02-14',
                       '2022-02-14', '2022-02-14',
                       '2022-02-16', '2022-02-17',
                       '2022-02-19', '2022-02-19',
                       '2022-02-19', '2022-02-19',
                       '2022-02-16', '2022-02-12',
                       '2022-02-12', '2022-02-13']
                   }
```

I am connecting to a table via sqlalchemy like so:

```
incidents = select(
            incidents.c.type,
            incidents.c.id,
            incidents.c.date
        ).subquery()

result = self.connection.execute(incidents).fetchall()
```

Is it even possible in plain sql? Maybe I should use pandas in order to apply a rolling window?

Comment: Don't use Pandas for this; do use SQL.

Comment: In your range 2022-02-12 - 2022-02-17, is the last day exclusive? I hope so, otherwise you have conflicting information.

Comment: I count eight occurrences in the first window, so you're going to need to clarify how you calculate "occurrence".

Comment: You are right. I actually have two test sets and I added the conflicting one. So the date range is inclusive and it is calculated as you interpreted it. The example is related to the formatted table at the beginning, not the test_data_small. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect this

Comment: There you go, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, this problem should be solved in `SQL`. In particular, it can be solved using plain `SQL`. Notice that you therefore only need to use one `join`: You can `join` your table with itself on the date range which is spanned by the window size, and on the type, and then count the corresponding entries.

Using the test data you provided yields the following result.

```
select
t.id, t.type, t.date, count(*) as num_inc_next_5_days
from tbl as t
    inner join tbl i
            on t.date >= dateadd(day,-5,i.date)
               and t.date <= i.date
               and t.type = i.type
group by t.id, t.type, t.date
order by t.type, t.id, t.date

|----|------|------------|---------------------|
| id | type | date       | num_inc_next_5_days |
|----|------|------------|---------------------|
| 1  | A    | 2022-02-12 | 6                   |
| 2  | A    | 2022-02-14 | 9                   |
| 3  | A    | 2022-02-14 | 9                   |
| 4  | A    | 2022-02-14 | 9                   |
| 5  | A    | 2022-02-16 | 6                   |
| 6  | A    | 2022-02-17 | 5                   |
| 7  | A    | 2022-02-19 | 4                   |
| 8  | A    | 2022-02-19 | 4                   |
| 9  | A    | 2022-02-19 | 4                   |
| 10 | A    | 2022-02-19 | 4                   |
| 0  | B    | 2022-02-16 | 1                   |
| 1  | B    | 2022-02-12 | 4                   |
| 2  | B    | 2022-02-12 | 4                   |
| 3  | B    | 2022-02-13 | 2                   |
```

The last column shows the number of incidents within the next five days, including the current date. If you want to get the maximum of these incidents, just wrap the query inside a `cte` and take the maximum:

```
with cte as (
...
)
select max(...) 
from cte
```

Used data:

```
create table tbl (
    id int,
    type varchar(1),
    date date
)

insert into tbl values
(1, 'A', '2022-02-12'),
(2, 'A', '2022-02-14'),
(3, 'A', '2022-02-14'),
(4, 'A', '2022-02-14'),
(5, 'A', '2022-02-16'),
(6, 'A', '2022-02-17'),
(7, 'A', '2022-02-19'),
(8, 'A', '2022-02-19'),
(9, 'A', '2022-02-19'),
(10, 'A', '2022-02-19'),
(0, 'B', '2022-02-16'),
(1, 'B', '2022-02-12'),
(2, 'B', '2022-02-12'),
(3, 'B', '2022-02-13');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is so useful. How would you go about getting the maximum for each type? With this cte statement?

Comment: You are welcome. If you want to have the maximum per `type`, then you have to group by `type`, e.g. `SELECT type, MAX(num_inc_next_5_days) FROM cte GROUP BY type ORDER BY type`. This would return two rows for the example above: `(type, MAX(...))`: `('A', 9)` and `('B', 4)`.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Comment: What is the problem / error message?

Comment: Hey, in the meantime I got it working. Thank you so much. I know it's a bit much to just ask the next question, but I seem to struggle with this cte statement. How would I go about including the date interval in the result? I grouped the statement by         SELECT type, MAX(num_inc_next_5_days)
        FROM cte
        GROUP BY type.     But now I want to include the date interval where the maximum value occured and I can't seem to figure out how to use the date in the outer select without including it in the GROUP BY.

Comment: It is not too much, but you should write a new question for this. Add your existing code (e.g. minimal example as above) and ask how to get the date interval. You can also include a reference to this question using a link. The original question was answered, therefore I would not discuss this here in more detail, since it is off-topic ...